# how can pandas plot 2 pdf in same graph?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

If only 1 line, i can plot, learn from below 
[Plot Normal distribution with Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20011494/plot-normal-distribution-with-matplotlib/20026448)

e.g , i have a pandas like below:

```
name,distance
Peter,13
Sam,14
Peter,15
Sam,12
Sam,13
Peter,14
```

With `df.groupby('name').describe()` I can display some min/max/mean by each of a user.

However, I want to draw a normal distribution base on existing data. 
i tried `df.sort_values(by='name').groupby('name').plot()`

but it wont draw a pdf or normal distribution for it.
How can I use numpy to achieve that

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, what you want is to plot a `distance` histogram for both `name` values in the same plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['Peter', 'Sam', 'Peter', 'Sam', 'Sam', 'Peter'],
         'distance':[13, 14, 15, 12, 13, 14]})

for name in df['name'].unique():      
  plt.hist(df.loc[df['name']==name, 'distance'], label=name)    
plt.legend();
```

[image]

---

**UPDATE:**

As OP suggested in the comments, it's possible to draw these without a for loop.

```
df.groupby('name').distance.plot.hist()
df.groupby('name').distance.plot.kde()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but i want draw a distribution graph not this kind of graph, and all running on same graph. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I found the solution,
`df.groupby('name').distance.plot.kde()`

Comment: Thank @KennethYeung I just learned what I did is also possible without a for loop. Updated the answer for future reference.