# plotting normal distribution with matplot won't give a bell shape

Tags: python, matplotlib, normal-distribution

As with this post [Plot Normal distribution with Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20011494/plot-normal-distribution-with-matplotlib)
have about the same issue. but I'm not able to get bell shape

I have the following code :

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import norm
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data = {'Age':[69, 74, 68, 70, 72, 67, 66, 70, 76, 68, 72, 79, 74, 67, 66, 71, 74, 75, 75, 76],
        'Weight':[153, 175, 155, 135, 172, 150, 115, 137, 200, 130, 140, 265, 185, 112, 140, 150, 165, 185, 210, 220]} 

data = pd.DataFrame(data) 
data = data.sort_values(by=['Age'])
data.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
x_mean = np.mean(data['Age'])
stdx = np.std(data['Age'])

plt.plot(data['Age'], norm.pdf(data['Age'],x_mean,stdx),'-o')
plt.hist(data['Age'], normed=True)      

plt.title("Standard Normal")
plt.xlabel("Value")
plt.ylabel("Density")
plt.show()
```

The data is sorted.

```
The mean is : 71.450
The standard deviation is : 3.8178
```

Comment: from where you get variables:  `norm.pdf(data['Age'],x_mean,stdx`?

Comment: I guess `norm.pdf` comes from scipy, so you'd need to do `import scipy.stats.norm as norm`. Can you edit your code to make it executable? Mean and stdev will also need to be defined / calculated, probably using `np.mean(data['Age']), np.std(data['Age'])` after importing numpy. - What is your question? If you plot the data, it will be far away from a perfect bell shape, but that's just what the data is...